# Pass data with a redirection

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can someone help me with a short example if we want redirect a user to /mypage.aspx and passing with this redirection some data (let's say 2 parameters)

What is the correct syntax to do this?

Comment: do a simple google search on `C# asp.net creating a QueryString` it's not that difficult. also can you show us what you have tried on your own..?

Comment: Very vague.  Need more code examples of where you are and what your trying to accomplish

Comment: it's quite simple what the OP is wanting .. they want to pass 2 parameters to a Response.Redirect method.. this is not difficult

Comment: If this is the case google will work.  However maybe it's a parameter being passed in SQL but maybe it's something that would be passed in a hidden field.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Classic ASP - they are different technologies. Can you remove the tag, please?

Comment: @ xxmrlnxx re-read the question what does this have to do with SQL

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks @JohnSaunders it's my first time when i post question in stackoverflow that's why i did many errors , Thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass information between pages in various ways, some of which depend on how the redirection occurs.

Here you can see how it can be done:

[How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= Button1.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            var data = { mo:5, dy:11, yr:2015 };
            var json1 = JSON.stringify(data);
            //var ser = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(data); 
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: json1,
                url: "mypage.aspx /GetDate",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#<%= TextBox4.ClientID %>").val(result.d);
                },
                error: function (status, ex) {
                    alert("Error Code: Status: " + status + " Ex: " + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetDate(string mo, string dy, string yr)
    {
        json1 = "{ mo:mo, dy:dy, yr:yr }";
       return json1;
    }
```